# WebView2 not working on virtual machine in WinForms

Tags: winforms, virtual-machine, webview2, .net-7.0

I am working on a Winforms project in .Net-7.0 and using WebView2 to display an HTML page available online.

The app works fine in the local system so I know there is no coding related problem but once installed on a VM, WebView2 does not show the HTML page.

I have opened the HTML page in the VM browser and it opens fine so the site is not blocked either in some way.
Any other things that I should check for?

(Skipping the code because it does not look like a code related problem to me.)

Comment: Did you follow the guidelines in [Distribute your app and the WebView2 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution), to install the Evergreen (auto-updating) run-time? Are you using the same (latest) version? -- Posting the WebView2 initialization code you have is a good idea anyway

Comment: Note that there's a [WebView2 Deployment Visual Studio installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentvsinstallersample) project available. It includes the WebView2 run-time detection and allows to download it when it's missing. Or a similar [WiX Custom Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/samples/wv2deploymentwixcustomactionsample) -- Windows 11 machines should already have the automatic updater available